# Angular Material Select list with filter

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a simple select list using  [Angular Material List Module](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview)

The trouble is - I am trying to combine this with a filter. I have achieved this functionality however I am unable to filter and un-filter the list without it losing track of which items within the list as selected. This is because during the filter, items which were previously selected are removed when they are "filtered out".

A second version was a simple @for loop of mat-checkbox's however this requires a function to determine if the item is selected or not which is VERY expensive. Something like:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="w-full">
   <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
   <input matInput formControlName="itemFilter" (ngModelChange)="filterItem($event)" />
</mat-form-field>

<div class="w-full flex-column my-list d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
@for(s of filteredOptions; track s){
    <mat-checkbox class="w-full" [checked]="isSelected(s)" (click)="toggleSelected(s)">{{s.name}} ({{s.code}})</mat-checkbox>
}
</div>
```

**Component**

```
filterItem($event: any): void {
    if (!$event) {
      this.filteredOptions = this.origList;
    }
    if (typeof $event === 'string') {
      this.filteredOptions = this.origList.filter((a) =>
        a.name.toLowerCase().startsWith($event.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }


isSelected(item: MyItem): boolean {
    return (this.searchForm.get('selectedItems')?.value as MyItem[]).indexOf(item) > -1;
  }

toggleSelectedShed(item: MyItem) {
    const current = this.searchForm.get('selectedItems')
      ?.value as MyItem[];
    if (current.indexOf(item) > -1) {
      // Remove it
      current.splice(current.indexOf(item), 1);
    } else {
      // Add it
      current.push(item);
    }

    this.searchForm.get('selectedItems')?.patchValue(current);
  }
```

This function is basically run for every item during any change.

Is there another option which allows the filtering but doesn't have these drawbacks?

I have dropped the filtering requirement to pursue the simple checkbox array. This too seems problematic [Stackblitz to my work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/djs2yr?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcheckbox-reactive-forms-example.css)

Comment: Could you include how your are filtering the options and getting the `filteredOptions`? I am thinking that it might be good to leverage an observable that combines the filtered options with the form value and augments the option to include whether it's selected or not. But without the rest of the code, I am not sure if that will work.

Comment: Added filter code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to solve this with using a `FormArray` and a pipe to do the filtering. The selected state is stored in each of the form array items, so you never need to check it's selected state on each item.

**Component**

```
const items: Item[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Item 1', selected: false },
  { id: 2, name: 'Item 2', selected: false },
  { id: 3, name: 'Item 3', selected: false },
  { id: 4, name: 'Item 4', selected: false },
  { id: 5, name: 'Item 5', selected: false },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FilterItemsPipe],
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterText">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <ul formArrayName="items">
        @for (item of itemsFormArray.controls | filterItems : filterText; track $index) {
          <li [formGroup]="item">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected">
              {{ item.value.name }}
            </label>
          </li>
        }
      </ul>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class SelectListComponent {
  filterText = '';
  itemsFormArray = new FormArray(items.map((item) => new FormGroup({
    selected: new FormControl(item.selected),
    id: new FormControl(item.id),
    name: new FormControl(item.name),
  })));
  form = new FormGroup({
    items: this.itemsFormArray,
  });
}
```

**Pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterItems',
  standalone: true,
})
export class FilterItemsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: FormGroup[], filterText: string | undefined | null): FormGroup[] {
    if (!filterText) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter((item) => (item.value.name ?? '').toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase()));
  }

}
```

Comment: Please see my StackBlitz - The issue is the checked status is lost when filtering and unfiltering

Comment: You almost had it. You just missed the `[checked]="s.selected"` binding on your checkboxes. I still recommend you implement it the way I show above though because in my example the form holds the checked/unchecked states. But, it will ultimately depend on how you plan on using the list of values. Regardless, if you add the binding above, your code works.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - unfortunately the checkbox list does not render and seems to partially load whenever the page is interacted with. I have tried adding a signal for when the load is complete but that doesn't help. i also tried a change detector but nothing.

Comment: If you had implemented my answer, it would work just fine. There are several differences between my implementation and yours. One critical difference is that the form group inside the `@for` is the form group for the item, not the root form group.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating two lists then modifying the display:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-list-example',
  templateUrl: './select-list-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-list-example.component.css']
})
export class SelectListExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  items = [{ name: 'Item 1', code: '001' }, { name: 'Item 2', code: '002' }]; // Example items array
  filteredItems = [...this.items]; // Initialize filteredItems with the full items array
  selectForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    // Initialize the form with an empty array for selected items
    this.selectForm = new FormGroup({
      selectedItems: new FormControl([]),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.applyFilter(''); // Apply no filter initially
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    // Filter the items based on the filterValue
    // For simplicity, this example filters by name
    this.filteredItems = this.items.filter(item =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  }

  toggleSelected(item: any) {
    const currentSelectedItems = this.selectForm.get('selectedItems')?.value;
    const index = currentSelectedItems.findIndex(selectedItem => selectedItem.code === item.code);
    if (index > -1) {
      // Item is already selected, remove it
      currentSelectedItems.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      // Item is not selected, add it
      currentSelectedItems.push(item);
    }
    this.selectForm.get('selectedItems')?.setValue([...currentSelectedItems]);
  }

  isSelected(item: any): boolean {
    const currentSelectedItems = this.selectForm.get('selectedItems')?.value;
    return currentSelectedItems.some(selectedItem => selectedItem.code === item.code);
  }
}
```

and then the html:

```
<div class="w-full flex-column my-list d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
      <form [formGroup]="selectForm">
        <div *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">
          <mat-checkbox class="w-full" [checked]="isSelected(item)" (click)="toggleSelected(item)">
            {{item.name}} ({{item.code}})
          </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is almost the same code as I wrote - whilst I do not disagree it works. if you were to console log everytime the isSelected function is called - you would notice it run A LOT. This is what I am trying to avoid.